# Better way to load Large json object client side

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, ldap

I have a large json file (ldap) that I need to populate client side. This needs to load the nested groups and then load the members associated with that group. 
My first thought was to use jquery and an Ajax call to load the json:

```
$(function displayGroupItems() {
$('.group-submit').click(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url:'ldap/groups',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#dropdown").append('<div>' + data.cn +'</div><div>' + data.ou '</div>');
        }
    "error": function (result) {
        var response = result.responseText;
        alert('Error loading: ' + response);
    }
    });
});
});
```

This method does respond with the json data. However, it won't populate the entire list in my dom elements and frankly takes to long to parse the thousands of lines we have.

Is there a better way to load a large json object?

Thank you

Comment: Can you not paginate the groups so that there would be smaller JSON sections?

Comment: Well the issue is that I want to edit LDAP groups and users on the fly. And then send that response back. So I’m not sure if this is even the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot control the service and the data that is returned, you might consider:

1. Only loading the portions you need
2. Use local storage to save this data and only perform the query once per session. [Jquery local storage](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/localstorage/)